# Source Code for Entity framework 6.0.2

Tags: entity-framework, entity, entity-framework-6

Why is there no source code history for entity framework:

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/releases/view/114074

We can download and build the latest release 6.1 (alpha) which we dont want to do but we cannot download and build earlier releases 6.0.2 (stable) which we do want to do?

Can anyone point me in the direction of finding that source code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download source code directly from the [Git repository](http://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6).

The revision [7648d33dfb53589d9c32b605c61758a5a6c0b80b](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/commit/7648d33dfb53589d9c32b605c61758a5a6c0b80b) is tagged with 6.0.2 tag.

Comment: Please update a link, I am receiving error 500 from http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/, the link to clone the repository from Codeplex have change to https://git01.codeplex.com/entityframework

Comment: from EF codeplex page, seems the project move to github: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6