# Is Entity .Find() aware of state changes to the DataBase?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

If I'm using `.Find()` instead of `.Where()` to query an object, and someone updates the database making the in memory model out of sync, does Entity know/is Entity alerted to the change so that it updates the model in memory?

Does `.Find()` expose me to the risk of missing data?

Comment: This is precisely why you use a new context for each DB operation.

Comment: Does a new context cancel out the performance improvements that `.Find()` brings?

Comment: How do you know there are performance improvements?  Seems like there's evidence that [`Find` is actually _slower_ than `First()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686225/dbset-find-method-ridiculously-slow-compared-to-singleordefault-on-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is Entity alerted to the change so that it updates the model in memory?

No. I've never seen an ORM that does that. It is possible, but not trivial. You can read more about it in [Query Notifications in SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx). And that's not even the whole story because once you can listen to database events you'd heave to decide what to do with them client-side. Like, what to do with changed values that were *also* changed in the client?

But the `Find` method is designed to do almost the opposite. It always tries to return an object from the local cache. It only queries the database if the object isn't there yet. So it's designed to return stale data, if you like. It is perfect for relatively complex operations in which you're going to need an object multiple times, but don't want to get it from the database all the time.

LINQ query statements (`Find` isn't LINQ) are somewhere in the middle. They do query the database, but *they don't update objects* that are in the cache already. If you changed an object locally, the changes won't be erased by a `Select` statement.

You can refresh the local cache, but the `DbContext` API, which was an improvement of the former `ObjectContext` API, even makes that a bit less easy than before. The message is: don't do it. If you want fresh data: create a new context.

Answer (score 0):

> Does `.Find()` expose me to the risk of missing data?

Sure, but so does `First()` and `Where()`.  Any time you load data into memory you risk the data behind it changing without your knowledge.  You can *minimize* that risk in EF by not hanging on to entities for long periods of time, and using a new context for every DB operation (or operations).

Comment: I thought `.Where()` always queried the database, regardless of dbcontext. Is that wrong?

Comment: It might, but even if it does, you should use a new context when loading data from the DB (unless it;s part of a larger unit of work), so what does it matter?